# Firebase Auth: How to make admin.auth().importUsers match auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm working on a app where I want to use firebase's Email/Password sign in method for authentication. From the client, creating a new user works fine with the  `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method - I can later log in as expected using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`. So far, so good.

However, I need to regularly import a list of users on the server, and for that I would like to use the `admin.auth().importUsers` method from the Firebase functions app, as it lets me create up to 1000 users in a single step.

My problem is that I haven't found out how to use the `admin.auth().importUsers` method so that the user(s) created that way matches what `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` gave me - at least I can not log a user created that way.

So, my question is: Is there a way to create new users using the  `admin.auth().importUsers` method in a way that later can be logged in on the client using the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` method?

Comment: What doesn't match between the two methods? Are you saying that the password doesn't work after import?

Comment: Yes, Doug. I'm not able to log in, probably because I haven't used the correct hash options corresponding to what createUserWithEmailAndPassword uses... (see Hiranya's answer and my comments below).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correct password hash and the corresponding hash options when importing the users. For example for HMAC hashed passwords:

```
const currentRawPassword = 'password';
const currentRawSalt = 'NaCl';
const options = {
  hash: {
    algorithm: 'HMAC_SHA256',
    key: Buffer.from('secret'),
  },
};
const currentHashKey = options.hash.key.toString('utf8');
const passwordHash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', currentHashKey)
  .update(currentRawPassword + currentRawSalt).digest();

const importUserRecord = {
  uid,
  email,
  passwordHash,
  passwordSalt: Buffer.from(currentRawSalt),
};
await admin.auth().importUsers([importUserRecord], options);
```

Adapted from the integration tests in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/auth.spec.ts

Also see the examples at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users

Comment: Thank you Hiranya!

Comment: Yes, I realize that I would have to use one of the encryption models specified in the docs. 

But the question is: Wich one would give me the identical user data as if it was created using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method?

Comment: Any one of them would work as long as you configure the hash options correctly. Note that in the integration tests, each user is imported and then verified by a call to [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/auth.spec.ts#L1949). Firebase Auth rehashes passwords using a [modified scrypt function](https://github.com/firebase/scrypt/). You can directly use it in your code too if you like.

Comment: Thanks again, Hiranya! I was able to break out the SCRYPT-related code from the Integration tests, generate a user that way and log in. 

The test example uses hardcoded scryptPasswordHash, so I still have to figure out how to use the scrypt lib - but that's another story! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i would like to comment, but i cant so..  I am not very into that importUsers feature,but did you already simply tried it for a testuser, which you import with importUsers and then try to sign in with the signInWithEmailAndPassword? 
If this does not work maybe its a deal to iterate through your users list and just create them manually?